# Why does printf("value: %f",10/2); output 0.000000?

Tags: c, floating-point, int, printf

I knew integer arithmetic will truncate fractions but here it should at least print 5. Why is it printing `0.000000`?

Comment: In C, integer division produces an integer result.  If you try to use a floating point format `%f` with an integer, the result is undefined behavior.  Try changing the format to `%d` (or cast the division result to `double`).

Answer (score 5):

The call of `printf` has undefined behavior because the conversion specifier `%f` does not correspond to the type of the expression `10 / 2`, which is `int`. As the two operands of the expression `10 / 2` have the type `int`, the result has the type `int` because it is the common type of the both operands.

Use instead at least `10.0 / 2`. In this case, the expression has the type `double`.

Or output the integer expression `10 /2` using conversion specifier `%d` or `%i` like

```
printf( "value: %d", 10 / 2 );
```

From the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> 9 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.275) **If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined**.

Comment: We tried with those, we are able to get answer with typecasting and all. but here we would like to find out why printf() has undefined behaviour ? If possible please help us with bit more details on it, because we are students we really wanna know about it.

Comment: @Ganesh It has undefined behavior by the definition. See the quote form the C Standard in my answer. The function printf incorrectly  interprets its argument that moreover has a different size then the type double.

Comment: @Ganesh When you pick a format specified in printf you are telling the printf implementation to treat the corresponding argument as being of appropriate type. You claimed to be passing a float, but actually supplied an int. What will actually happen depends on exactly how int and float data are passed as function call arguments, and their internal representation, so the standard leaves it undefined.

Answer (score 1):

`10` and `2` aren't valid `float`s. They are `int`s.

To have your program print correct output, do this:

```
printf("value:%f",10./2.);
```

Notice the `.` after each number. This signifies to the compiler that the number is a floating-point number.

Comment: Can we consider this printf("value:%f",10/2); as a function call with invalid parameters ?

Comment: @Ganesh Yes. You're trying to print an `int` value as a `float`.